# View repos in my GitHub organisation using ssh

Tags: git, github, github-organizations

I have been added to an organisation recently `https://www.github.com/examplecorp`

Is is possible to view the repository list in the Organization using SSH from my terminal ?
I have my public key deployed in my Github account .

Comment: GitHub.com use ssh only for authenticating and communicating with your git repository (hosted on github.com). Github.com user's related data are not stored in the git repository because that's not what is it for (it's for code)
What you're looking for is to use their HTTP API https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/orgs#list-organizations-for-the-authenticated-user

Comment: can you make an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github.com use SSH only for authentication and communicating with your git repository, which is hosted on GitHub.

Github user's related data (not git related) are not stored in the git repository because that's not their purpose, it's for storing code and revision.

The information you're looking at is therefore avalaible through their HTTP API, see https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/orgs#list-organizations-for-the-authenticated-user